# Display error while modifying the hoverinfo of the choropleth maps using ggplotly and choroplethrZip package in R

Tags: r, hover, ggplotly, choroplethr

I tried to modify the hoverinfo using style function of plotly and end up displaying the entire column information on every hover point.

I tried to use style function using <\n>, "br", "br /" and tooltip. The problem does not exist with ggplot objects converted to plotly objects.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrZip)

trips$region<- as.character(trips$zip)
trips$value<- as.numeric(trips$AVG_COST_PER_MILE)  
title <- paste("Average Cost Per Mile  ")
choropleths<- zip_choropleth(trips,title = title, state_zoom = 
"delaware") 

mytext=paste("Cost per Mile =", trips$AVG_COST_PER_MILE, "<br> Trip 
Count = ", trips$Trip_count, "<br>  Cityname",trips$CITY)
p<- ggplotly(choropleths)
style( p, text=mytext, hoverinfo = "text")
```

Sample Data:

```
trips<- trips<-structure(list(TIME = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L,10L, 10L, 10L), zip = c(19700L, 19711L, 19720L, 19730L, 19731L, 
19732L,19735L, 19801L, 19814L, 19901L), AVG_COST_PER_MILE = c(3.33, 
2.63, 2.05, 2.85, 2.98, 5.32, 3.37, 2.57, 3.5, 1.95), Trip_count = c(2L, 
1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 0L), CITY = structure(c(3L, 
6L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 4L), .Label = c(" Odessa", " 
Winterthur", "Delaware City", "Dover", "New Castle", "Newark", 
"Newport", "Port Penn", "Rockland", "Wilmington"), class = "factor"), 
latitude = c(39.57032, 39.70056, 39.66922, 39.45648, 39.51816, 39.7945, 
39.7944, 39.73856, 39.71363, 39.16426), longitude = c(-75.59066, 
-75.7431, -75.59003, -75.65976, -75.57656, -75.57433, -75.5976, 
-75.54833, -75.59628, -75.51163)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -10L))
```

I want to see hover-point display the appropriate information on a right point.